# Visual Studio 2008 Build order without using Project Dependency

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'd like to change the build order of projects in my C# solution, without having to rely on project dependencies.

Reason: solution takes approx 1 min 30 secs build locally. This is a little much, especially if you're making lots of minor changes.

My approach to fixing this is to have a mapped share (my R:) pointing to "..\ReferencedAssemblies". Each projects outdir points to "..\ReferencedAssemblies"
Any cross-project references are picked up from R:\assemblyName.dll, with Copylocal=false. This means that the dependent projects don't need to be rebuilt if the changes are only made to a single project.

I'm finding that this approach is saving a lot of local build time.

The final issue is changing the build order of the projects in the solution as a whole without relying on the dependencies. Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.
Padda

Comment: "1 min 30 secs build locally. This is a little much" --> if only! :)

Comment: By not having inter project dependencies, I think you're not giving Visual Studio's build runner enough information about the build order -- and short of a custom build process, I'm not sure if you can do anything about it.  If you have dependencies between projects, I strongly recommend doing project references rather than references to the output files.  You still get the benefit of fast builds (minus the time it takes to analyse dependencies between builds).

Comment: Hi Nader, 1 min 30 doesn't seem too bad, but it adds up to quite a bit over the course of a day, esp when doing lots of local builds. I'm not sure how VStudio 2008 decides upon the order when there's no project dependencies listed. Any help, always appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The order in which each project in your solution is built is determined by the inter-project dependencies, and is done automatically (excluding external dependencies). If your solution is taking a long time to build for small changes, then it is proably becuase code that has't changed is being re-compiled unnecessarily. Try making your solution more modular and remove unrequired dependencies.